# Can I use the SMTP server of the hosting provider instead of the domain name provider?

Tags: smtp

If I purchased my domain name, say `example.com`, from X but have hosted my website with Y, and now if I need to use an SMTP server for my domain, do I *have* to use the SMTP server of the company X, or can I even use company Y's SMTP server for the domain name `example.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inbound SMTP server is resolved using only DNS records within your domain, so you can use any SMTP provider exactly like you can use any web hosting provider.

(In general, domain sale, DNS hosting, web hosting, and mail hosting are four separate services – there is also no requirement to have DNS be managed by companies X or Y either.)

In DNS you'll use `MX` records to specify the servers for incoming mail, and `TXT "v=spf1"` records to specify which servers are allowed to send outgoing mail. Your mail provider will usually tell you what records you need to add.